# Magento cookie bug with WebKit based browsers

Tags: magento-1, cookie

There is a reasonably common & [well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome) [documented](http://web.archive.org/web/20160413200508/http://webdesignergeeks.com/cms/magento/how-to-fix-magento-login-problem-in-chrome) [cookie-related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717668/magento-installation-uable-to-access-admin-panel) [bug/issue](http://howlingwolf.de/blog/2011/12/magento-cookie-fuckup-chromesafari-webkit-engine-stuff/) with Magento and Chrome (looking at the others' issues - possibly WebKit and IE at times). Whether this is due to a common Chrome extension/setting or incorrect web server setting - I do not know.

I'm on OS X 10.8.2 running CentOS 5.8 via VirtualBox. More often than not, for me to login to a Magento admin, I need to set the HTTP Only setting in the Magento admin to 'No'. Before I do this, I am not able to login via Chrome - other browsers do not seem to have this issue for me.

Now I've come across a new (but probably the same) issue while making an extension - I am able to read cookies via Chrome but not set them. There were no issues with using Firefox. To make sure it's not my Chrome, I've performed a [fresh install](https://superuser.com/questions/318186/how-do-i-uninstall-google-chrome-completely-from-my-mac) by deleting all user data and profiles but the issue persists. Perhaps I should set the cookies via JS only for this extension.

Nothing out of the norm with the cookie setting code:

```
$cookie = Mage::getModel('core/cookie');
$cookie->set('cookiename','cookievalue',99999);
```

Comment: This should only affect you when you are running under localhost - or are you having problems in the production environment?

Comment: @mpaepper localhost only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't develop using `localhost` as your domain name.  I typically use apache to setup a fake custom site at a domain like `magento.dev`, and then add

```
127.0.0.1    magento.dev
```

to my hosts file. Beyond working around the cookie problem, this also lets me have an infinite number of sites running locally.

Comment: Yes I did have that - except my top level domain was .fk for my initials and Chrome did not like that. When this was changed to .local the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Is your server time and computer time correct? This causes the majority of cookie issues with Webkit based browsers - whereas IE and FF are far more tolerant (ignorant).

Comment: Not really considered an answer

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that Chrome interprets your custom web address differently from other browsers. I had a custom top level domain for my local installations but when this was changed to `.com` the issue was resolved and now it's set as `.local` (I was using `.fk` previously)