# Can't login with Safari on iPad - Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, login

I received a customer report that they can't login to our ecommerce site from their iPad.   I was able to recreate the issue with Safari, but Chrome on the iPad works fine.

What I see in Safari is the page seems to reload (posts to the server) but then returns to the login page without an error message in the browser.   Double-checked credentials, they are correct and, as I mentioned, work fine in Chrome.

Not even sure where to start diagnosing this issue.

Comment: is this happening on a live site?

Answer (score 3):

In `admin panel` goto

```
system->configuration->general->web->session cookie management
```

in the options add the following things

```
Cookie Lifetime: 86400 

Cookie Path: / 

Cookie Domain: Your Domain

Use HTTP Only: No 

Cookie Restriction Mode: No
```

Comment: This change did not make a difference.  Still unable to login with iPad/safari.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely has to do with cookies/sessions. I had a similar issue once affecting webkit browsers. Check your server time, it probably isn't right and/or is set in the incorrect timezone. If you want details about my issue you can find it here: [Magento cookie bug with WebKit based browsers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/796/magento-cookie-bug-with-webkit-based-browsers)

Ben's answer is probably most relevant to your case. I've also had a [login/cookie issue of another type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16349/double-frontend-cookies-causing-intermittent-login-issues).

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings in : System > Config > Web

```
Cookie Lifetime: 86400
Cookie Path:
Cookie Domain:
Use HTTP Only: YES
Cookie Restriction Mode: no
```

Important settings is HTTP Only: YES Rest of the settings will be default settings. This should work.

I tried all the other options in SO, but they didnt help me, so if anyone else is on same boat maybe try this.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently face this issue and found solution for this.may someone help this solution.Have nothing change in to core.and i also did research on google about this problem but every post i get is changes core file so i got the solution that without touching the core file.and it's also working fine for the chrome and safari.I did test it on my `magento version 1.8.0.0`

Below is image for configuration setting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that a try.  I will try at a non-peak time because changing the Cookie Domain could break people's current sessions.